# Rename a Prometheus label by using a regex against a metric name

Tags: prometheus

Let's say I have a metric named `metrics-app-123456-spark-whatever-1`.

I know you can use the following options for relabeling:

- https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config
- https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs

With these two I can either rename the metric name or the label, but in this case, **how can I use the app ID from the metric name to be added as a label**? Basically I do not see a way to rename a label using the regex from the metric name.

i.e. `metrics-app-123456-spark-whatever-1` -> `metrics-spark-whatever-1{app=123456}`

Comment: Have a look at [Extracting labels from legacy metric names](https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-labels-from-legacy-metric-names/). IIUC, the solution should apply to any metric names.

Comment: @DazWilkin That is exactly what I needed, I was not aware of the key missing point here, __name__ label. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm pleased to hear that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try the PromQL below:

`label_replace(label_replace(metrics-app-123456-spark-whatever-1{}, "app", "$3", "__name__", "(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)"), "__name__", "$1-$4-$5-$6", "__name__", "(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)")`

**Q: how can I use the app ID from the metric name to be added as a label?**

**A: Use the prometheus function:** [label_replace()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace)